# NodeJS async/await performance issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, rally

I'm trying to pull Rally Revision history for the past 24 hours using NodeJS/rally-node.

Obj hierarchy is : User Story -> Revision History -> Revisions

I could get the results properly, but it takes 35 seconds for 10 User Stories. I've embedded my sample code here. Any one please help me how can i improve the performance!

Thanks! 
Sundarrajan R

---

**Sample Code:**

```
'use strict'
let rally = require('rally');
let queryUtils = rally.util.query;

const restApi = rally({
  apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  apiVersion: 'v2.0',
  server: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com'
});

async function queryUserRevisions(revisions) {

  const params = {
    ref: revisions,
    start: 1,
    limit: 3,
    order: 'RevisionNumber DESC',
    fetch: ['RevisionNumber', 'Description', 'CreationDate', 'User']
  };

  return restApi.query(params);
}

async function queryUserRevisionHistory(RevisionHistory) {

  const params = {
    ref: RevisionHistory,
    start: 1,
    limit: 1,
    fetch: ['Revisions']
  }

  return restApi.query(params);
}

async function traceRevisions() {

  const startTime = new Date()
  let UserStories;
  let resultArray = [];

  const ts = last24Hours();

  const params = {
    type: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
    start: 1,
    pageSize: 200,
    limit: 100,
    order: 'FormattedID',
    fetch: ['Name', 'FormattedID', 'RevisionHistory'],
    query: queryUtils.where('LastUpdateDate ', '>', '2020-04-13T00:00Z'),
    scope: {
      workspace: '/workspace/11111111111',
      project: '/project/22222222222',
      up: false,
      down: true
    }
  };

  try {
    let response_one = await restApi.query(params);
    const UserStoryCount = response_one.Results.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < UserStoryCount; i++) {
      UserStories = response_one.Results[i];
      console.log(UserStories.FormattedID);

      let response_two = await queryUserRevisionHistory(UserStories.RevisionHistory)
      let response_three = await queryUserRevisions(response_two.Revisions);

      for (let j = 0; j < response_three.Results.length; j++) {
        let revision = response_three.Results[j];

        resultArray.push({
          FormattedID: UserStories.FormattedID,
          RevisionNumber: revision.RevisionNumber,
          Description: revision.Description,
          CreationDate: revision.CreationDate,
          UserName: revision.User._refObjectName
        });

      }
    }

    var endTime = new Date() - startTime;
    console.log('Execution time: %dms', endTime);
    return JSON.stringify(resultArray)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

module.exports.traceRevisions = traceRevisions;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible optimization would be to fetch them in parallel, instead of in series, using `Promise.all`:

EDIT: To be more specific than "fetch them", I mean to do the first query first - because the later ones depend on it - and then do all of the "queryUserRevisionHistory, then queryUserRevisions" chains in parallel with each other.

```
    async function traceRevisions() {

        ...

        try {
            let response_one = await restApi.query(params);

            let resultArrays = await Promise.all( response_one.Results.map( async UserStories => {

                console.log(UserStories.FormattedID);

                let response_two = await queryUserRevisionHistory(UserStories.RevisionHistory)
                let response_three = await queryUserRevisions(response_two.Revisions);

                return response_three.Results.map( revision => ({
                    FormattedID: UserStories.FormattedID,
                    RevisionNumber: revision.RevisionNumber,
                    Description: revision.Description,
                    CreationDate: revision.CreationDate,
                    UserName: revision.User._refObjectName
                }));
            }));

            let resultArray = [].concat( ...resultArrays );

            var endTime = new Date() - startTime;
            console.log('Execution time: %dms', endTime);
            return JSON.stringify(resultArray)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks for your comments. I'm unable to run the 3 API calls in parallel as all inter-dependent. 
1. Pulling the User Story 
2. Revision History by User Story 
3. Revisions by Revision ID

Comment: This solution essentially runs the following pseudocode: series( queryUserStory(), parallel( series( queryUserRevisionHistory(), queryUserRevisions() ) for each result )). Is this not what you're after? It looks like all the "Revision History by User Story"s depend on "Pulling the User Story", but not on each other?

Comment: Hi Jack, Sorry for the delayed reply. Can you please help on Series/Parallel stuff, i'm new to that stuff. How can i best use of that?